# Проблема при запуске

Tags: python, ursina

```
from ursina import *

app = Ursina()
window.color = color.black

cube = Entity(model='cube', rotation=(-15, 0, 0)), position=(0, 0, 0), scale=4, color=color.orange)

app.run()
```

после запуска выдает

```
  File "c:\Users\PC-TV\Desktop\Snakee 2\main.py", line 6
    cube = Entity(model='cube', rotation=(-15, 0, 0)), position=(0, 0, 0), scale=4, color=color.orange)
           ^
SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call
```

Пожалуйста помогите.

Comment: rotation=(-15, 0, 0)) - зачем здесь вторая скобка?

Comment: @strawdog спасибо большое!!!

Comment: предлагаю вам удалить этот вопрос, иначе его закроют.